# How to send a 'hand coded' http request?

Tags: http

For test and learning purpose, Is it a console available to send http request like

```
GET /index.html HTTP/1.1␍␊
 Host: www.example.com␍␊
 ␍␊
```

and get response.

I know curl is pretty handy, but what I what is to explore what's under the hood

or write the request in a text file and send it by curl?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Grab a hold of the [`netcat`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat) tool:

```
echo -en 'GET /index.html HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: stackoverflow.com\r\n\r\n'
 | nc stackoverflow.com 80
```

Comment: That's the tools I want, so neat!

Comment: You can also use the `telnet` command that (probably) came with your OS.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily construct http requests through [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) using something called [Composer](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/composer.asp) (formerly Request Builder). That is just one feature of Fiddler, it is a very useful tool. An alternative to Fiddler if you are only on Linux is [ParosProxy](http://www.parosproxy.org/). Again, this is a web proxy and is very useful. One feature is crafting http request (by clicking the menu "`Tools" => "Send HTTP(S) Requests"`)

Answer (score 0):

[`netcat`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nc) is nice to explore HTTP and do requests by hand. You can do `nc -C example.com 80` and start typing your request.
The web server will answer with the response.

```
$ nc -C example.com 80
GET / HTTP/1.0
Host: example.com

HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Age: 565382
Cache-Control: max-age=604800
[...]

<html>
<head>
    <title>Example Domain</title>
[...]
```

`-C` is used send CRLF as line-ending : `\n` are replaced by `\r\n`. In a script you probably don't want to use this, and do as [Fred Foo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9602379/3526865) anwser.

To explore more, [Burp](https://portswigger.net/burp/communitydownload) is the reference tool for inspecting Web Requests, but there are multiple open source alternatives.

For HTTPS requests, you can do the same thing with `openssl s_client -quiet -crlf -connect example.com:443`

Comment: heads up for macOS users: the flag is `-c` instead of `-C`